# WSREP connection to peer timed out, no messages seen in PT3S

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, galera

I'm running 3 node Galera cluster using `MariaDB-server-10.3.13-1.el7.centos.x86_64` and periodically seeing following errors in logs. I did google about this error but didn't find any good answer. Does anyone know what this error trying to say?

I did check network and packet loss and didn't find anything related network issue.

```
[root@ostack-infra-2-1-galera-container-56895f1b ~]# tail -f /var/log/mysql_logs/galera_server_error.log
2021-11-20 22:07:28 0 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
2021-11-20 22:07:28 24 [Note] WSREP: Synchronized with group, ready for connections
2021-11-20 22:07:28 24 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
2021-11-20 22:07:29 0 [Note] WSREP: Trying to continue unpaused monitor
2021-11-20 22:07:29 0 [Note] WSREP: Trying to continue unpaused monitor
2021-11-21  0:07:10 0 [Note] WSREP: (e951c46a, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 4b57a7fb with addr tcp://172.28.15.69:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S
2021-11-21  0:07:10 0 [Note] WSREP: (e951c46a, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting on, nonlive peers: tcp://172.28.15.69:4567
2021-11-21  0:07:11 0 [Note] WSREP: (e951c46a, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') reconnecting to 4b57a7fb (tcp://172.28.15.69:4567), attempt 0
2021-11-21  0:07:11 0 [Note] WSREP: (e951c46a, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection established to 4b57a7fb tcp://172.28.15.69:4567
2021-11-21  0:07:15 0 [Note] WSREP: (e951c46a, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting off
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is not an error, just a "note". If it were an actual error, it would say 'error'.

The meaning of the message: An attempt at connecting from this host to one of the two other hosts in the cluster timed out - and the timeout is set to 3 seconds.

However, as per the subsequent messages, it then tried connecting again, and thankfully this time it succeeded.

See [this page](https://galeracluster.com/library/documentation/galera-parameters.html#gmcast-peer-timeout) for documentation about the timeout.

I think this is just the sort of thing that happens in a network once in a while. This is why we have these timeout settings. As long as reconnecting succeeds, I don't think you need to worry too much.

For an explanation of what *could* happen if reconnecting fails, see [this post](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/galera-cluster-recovery-101-deep-dive-network-partitioning) in SeveralNine's database blog about network partitioning.